# Drawing the schematic diagram of algorithm

Tags: plotting, labeling, trees

The B-Spline function used the alogrithm as shown below:

> [image]

I would like to draw it in *Mathematica* (Although this is my first time to use `TreePlot`)

```
 TreePlot[
   {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 7, 4 -> 8, 5 -> 8, 5 -> 9,
    6 -> 9, 6 -> 10}, Right, VertexLabeling -> True,
    EdgeRenderingFunction -> (Arrow[#1, 0.1] &)]
```

> [image]

#### Question:

1.Is it possible to use some option to replace the tags like `"1","2"...` to the $N_{0,3},N_{0,2}...$?
2.How to make the treeplot looks symmetrically?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update:** functions to generate the edge list, indices and labels:

```
ClearAll[layersF, edgesF, subscF, indicesF];

layersF = Module[{k = 1}, Table[k++, {i, #}, {j, i}]] &;
edgesF = Flatten[Thread /@ Thread[# -> Partition[#2, 2, 1]] & @@@
                                 Partition[layersF[#], 2, 1], 2] &;
indicesF = Reverse[Thread /@ Thread[{Reverse@Range[0, Range[0, # - 1]], Range[0, # - 1]}]] &;
subscF = Style[Subscript[N, ## & @@ ##], 16, "Panel", Background -> None] & /@ # &;
labelF = Flatten[subscF /@ indicesF[#]] &;
```

Examples:

```
edgesF@4
```

> {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 7, 4 -> 8, 5 -> 8, 5 -> 9, 6 -> 9, 6 -> 10}

```
vlabels = labelF@4
```

> $ \left\{N_{0,3},N_{0,2},N_{1,2},N_{0,1},N_{1,1},N_{2,1},N_{0,0},N_{1,0},N_{2,0},N_{3,
>    0}\right\}$

```
el = edgesF@4;
vl = Flatten[layersF@4];
lbls = labelF@4;
vlabels = Thread[vl -> (Placed[#, Center] & /@ lbls)];
options = {VertexShapeFunction -> "Square", VertexSize -> {0.25`, 0.25`}, ImagePadding -> 20, 
   VertexStyle -> Hue[0.125`, 0.7`, 0.9`], ImageSize -> 400, BaseStyle -> Arrowheads[Large]};
```

By reversing the `VertexList` and the setting of `"VertexPartition"` suboption  (credit: @MichaelE2)  we can change orientation of the graph without the need for `Rotation`:

```
Graph[Reverse@vl, el, options, VertexLabels -> vlabels, 
 GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> Reverse[Range[4]]}]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** functions to generate vertex coordinates

Although we can easily get `Left` and `Right` orientations easily using `"MultipartiteEmbedding"`, a function to generate similar vertex coordinates may be useful to get all four orientations. Such a function would also be useful for `TreePlot` and `GraphPlot` that do not provide similar layouts.

The following two functions both take an integer (representing the number of layers) as input:

```
 vcoordsF = {1, .5} # & /@ SparseArray[
      CellularAutomaton[{Unitize[#[[1]] + #[[3]]] &, {}, 1},{{1}, 0}, #-1]]["NonzeroPositions"] &;
```

or

```
vcoordsF2 = With[{n = #-1}, Reverse@Flatten[Thread /@ 
                ({#, Range[2 n + 1][[# ;; -# ;; 2]]} & /@ Range[n + 1]), 1]] &;
```

Examples:

```
gF1 = Graph[edgesF@#, ImageSize -> #2, options,
    VertexLabels -> Thread[Range@(# (# + 1)/2) -> (Placed[#, Center] & /@ (labelF@#))], 
    VertexCoordinates -> (-vcoordsF[#])] &;

Row[gF1 @@ # & /@ {{3, 250}, {5, 400}, {6, 500}}]
```

[image]

```
gF2 = Graph[edgesF@#, ImageSize -> #2, options,
    VertexLabels -> Thread[Range@(# (# + 1)/2) -> (Placed[#, Center] & /@ (labelF@#))], 
    VertexCoordinates -> (Reverse /@ vcoordsF[#])] &;

Row[gF2 @@ # & /@ {{3, 250}, {5, 400}, {6, 500}}]
```

[image]

Using with `TreePlot` (without subscripted labels)

```
TreePlot[edgesF@#, ImageSize -> #2, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabeling -> True, 
      VertexCoordinateRules -> (vcoordsF2[#])] & @@ # & /@ 
  {{3, 250}, {5, 400}, {12, 500}} // Row
```

[image]

---

**Previous version**

First, a helper function to get the subscript indices:

```
indicesF = Reverse[Thread /@ Inner[List, Reverse@Range[0, Range[0, #]], Range[0, #], List]] &;
```

And another to style and rotate indexed labels:

```
rssF = Rotate[Style[Subscript[N, #[[1]], #[[2]]], 16, "Panel", Background -> None], -Pi] &;

rlabels = Flatten[rss /@ # & /@ indicesF[3]]; 
vlabels = Table[i -> Placed[rlabels[[i]], Center], {i, Length@labels}];
```

Use the `"MultipartiteEmbedding"` suboption of the option `GraphLayout` to get the vertex coordinates as desired:

```
edgelist = {1->2, 1->3, 2->4, 2->5, 3->5, 3->6, 4->7, 4->8, 5->8, 5->9, 6->9, 6->10};
Rotate[Graph[edgelist, VertexShapeFunction -> "Square", VertexStyle -> Hue[0.125, 0.7, 0.9],
  VertexSize -> {.25, .25},  VertexLabels -> vlabels, ImagePadding -> 20, 
  GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> {1, 2, 3, 4}}], Pi]
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is very closely to what I need, I think I could finish the subscript according to your solution :-)

Comment: @ShutaoTang, updated with the subscript indices.

Comment: So surprised！+2,,:-)

Comment: @thank_you, thank you, thank you:)

Answer (score 10):

### Creating the edge list

The index and edges can be worked out like this:

```
step[list_, n_] := Block[
  {
   ln1 = list[[1]]
   , ln2 = list[[2]]
   },
  Join[
   If[ln2 < n ,
    {{ln1, ln2 + 1} -> {ln1, ln2}}, {}],
   If[ln2 < n,
    {{ln1, ln2 + 1} ->  {ln1 + 1, ln2  }}, {}],
   If[ln1 + ln2 + 1 < n,
    step[{ln1, ln2 + 1}, n], {}],
   If[ln1 + ln2 + 1 < n,
    step[{ln1 + 1, ln2}, n], {}]
   ]]

edgelist = DeleteDuplicates@step[{0, 0}, 3]
```

> ```
> {{0, 1} -> {0, 0}, {0, 1} -> {1, 0}, {0, 2} -> {0, 1}, {0, 2} -> {1,    1}, {0, 3} -> {0, 2}, {0, 3} -> {1, 2}, {0, 4} -> {0, 3}, {0, 4} -> {1, 3}, {1, 3} -> {1, 2}, {1, 3} -> {2, 2}, {1, 2} -> {1, 1}, {1, 2} -> {2, 1}, {2, 2} -> {2, 1}, {2, 2} -> {3, 1}, {1, 1} -> {1, 0}, {1, 1} -> {2, 0}, {2, 1} -> {2, 0}, {2, 1} -> {3, 0}, {3, 1} -> {3, 0}, {3, 1} -> {4, 0}}
> ```

The main difference is that I'm using both indexes as vertex, and generating the graphs programatically by a recursion, allowing any arbitrary length, but unfortunately with duplicates.

### Visualizing the graph

Building up from @kguler i.e copying shamelessly

```
edgelist = DeleteDuplicates@step[{0, 0}, 4];
vl = VertexList@Graph@edgelist;
```

> ```
> {{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 2}, {1, 1}, {0, 3}, {1, 2}, {0, 4}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}}
> ```

```
labels = Style[Subscript[N, #[[1]], #[[2]]], 16, "Title", Background -> None] & /@ vl ;
vlabels = #1 -> Placed[#2, Center] & @@@ Transpose[{vl, labels}];
Graph[
 edgelist
 , VertexLabels -> vlabels
 , VertexSize -> .5
 , VertexCoordinates -> ({#2, -#1 - #2/2} & @@@ vl )
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Another difference is that I'm defining the [`VertexCoordinates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexCoordinates.html) explicitly based on the index.

Answer (score 9):

A function to recursively generate the edges:

```
n[_, 0] := {};
n[x : 0, y_Integer] /; y > 0 :=
  {{x, y} -> {x, y - 1}, {x, y} -> {x + 1, y - 1}, n[x + 1, y - 1], n[x, y - 1]};
n[x_Integer, y_Integer] /; y > 0 :=
  {{x, y} -> {x, y - 1}, {x, y} -> {x + 1, y - 1}, n[x + 1, y - 1]};
```

We have to sort the vertices so that the `"MultipartiteEmbedding"` method can partition the vertices into groups with the right order.

```
With[{edges = Flatten@n[0, 3]},
 Graph[
  SortBy[VertexList@Graph@edges, Last],
  edges,
  VertexSize -> {0.22, 0.22}, 
  VertexLabels -> (idx_ :> Placed[Subscript[N, Sequence @@ idx], Center]),
  EdgeShapeFunction -> GraphElementData["FilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> 0.04], 
  EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], RGBColor[0.4, 0.4, 0.8]],
  GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> {4, 3, 2, 1}}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Update for V8**

The setting `"MultipartiteEmbedding"` was introduced in V9.  It seems to be simply ignored in V8.  Also rendering is different.  In V8, one can get the above result by explicitly computing the coordinates and using the default edge rendering.  The height and width can be adjusted in the `ncoords` code by multiplying `Range[0, y]` by a number or adding a number other than `1` in `First[#] + 1`, respectively.

```
ncoords[x_Integer, y_Integer] := 
  Flatten[Thread /@ 
    NestList[{First[#] + 1, MovingAverage[Last@#, 2]} &, {0, Range[0, y]}, y],
    1];

With[{edges = Flatten@n[0, 3], coords = ncoords[0, 3]}, 
 Graph[SortBy[VertexList@Graph@edges, Last], edges, 
  VertexSize -> {0.22, 0.22}, 
  VertexLabels -> (idx_ :> Placed[Subscript[N, Sequence @@ idx], Center]), 
  EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], RGBColor[0.4, 0.4, 0.8]], 
  VertexCoordinates -> coords]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! BTW, why the graph that generated by your code in V8 is different from what you have given?

Comment: @ShutaoTang The setting `"MultipartiteEmbedding"` was introduced in V9. I've updated my answer with a V8 solution.

Comment: @ShutaoTang You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 8):

Just use `TreePlot` with `VertexCoordinateRules`. I have tried like this.

```
treePlot[k_] := Module[{grp, pos},
   grp = DeleteCases[Flatten@Table[
       {n[j, i - j] -> n[j, i - 1 - j], 
        n[j, i - j] -> n[j + 1, i - 1 - j]},
       {i, k}, {j, 0, i}], n[__] -> n[_, _?(# < 0 &)]];
   pos = Flatten@Table[n[j, i - j] -> {(j + i)/3, i - j}, {i, 0, k}, {j, 0, i}];
   TreePlot[grp, Right, n[0, k], ImageSize -> 70 k, 
    VertexLabeling -> True, VertexCoordinateRules -> pos, 
    EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Arrowheads -> Small, Arrow[#, 0.3]} &)]
   ] /. n[a_, b_] -> Subscript[N, a, b]
```

Test

```
Manipulate[treePlot[k], {{k, 3}, 1, 10, 1},
 ContentSize -> {300, 200}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

> [image: Blockquote]