# Plot tree edges of a tree-form list

Tags: graphics, visualization, trees

I'm trying to plot a tree from a tree-form list. The nodes should be connected from left to right (as usual). My range values are

```
m = {{5}, {4, 6}, {3, 5, 7}, {2, 4, 6, 8}}
```

The corresponding domain values are `{0,1,2,3}`

Naturally, this tree can grow larger.

Any constructive idea or guidance are greatly appreciated.

Here is a sample output plot (did it in Excel).
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `TreeForm[m]`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want here. What is the output supposed to look like exactly?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. @m_goldberg : just tried `TreeForm[m]`, but it places all values at the final nodes. I need the progressing as I on the picture I posted. Just a regular tree plot. It's probably possible with `TreeForm[m]`, but I'd need to transform my input `m` somehow. @march: thanks. posted a sample plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspected `LayeredGraphPlot` may be helpful. I post this in case it assists in achieving goal.

```
m = {{5}, {4, 6}, {3, 5, 7}, {2, 4, 6, 8}};
r = Range[10];
rule = Thread[r -> Flatten[m]];
f[a_, b_] := MapThread[Function[{x, y}, {x, #} & /@ y]
   , {a, b}];
rag = Internal`PartitionRagged[r, {1, 2, 3, 4}];
u =Rule @@@Flatten[f[#1, Partition[#2, 2, 1]] & @@@Partition[rag, 2, 1], 2];
LayeredGraphPlot[u, Left, DirectedEdges -> False, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[#, 0.3], 
     Black, Text[#2 /. rule, #1]} &)]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. It should get me closer. I'll play with it now to try to work out the vertical positioning of nodes.

Comment: Was sifting through script logic, but faced an error message: `Flatten::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Flatten[part,2]. >>`

Comment: @EmilyHill could you clarify? Did the code not run or did you use a different case or are running components of code or something else?

Comment: I tried to run the code, but faced the error posted earlier. Now, trying to figure out what might have caused this error :) Let me know, if this clarified it or if you need more info. Thanks @ubpdqn

Comment: @EmilyHill it was my error `part` was referred to any was omitted in my cut and paste. I have posted corrected code. It runs now but check. Thank you for your patience. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using the functions `layersF` and `edgesF` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63477/125):

```
ClearAll[layersF, edgesF];
layersF = Module[{k = 1}, Table[k++, {i, #}, {j, i}]] &;
edgesF = Flatten[Thread /@ Thread[# -> Partition[#2, 2, 1]] & @@@ 
   Partition[layersF[#], 2, 1], 2]&;

m = {{5}, {4, 6}, {3, 5, 7}, {2, 4, 6, 8}};
el = edgesF @ Length[m];
vlabels = Thread[Flatten[layersF@Length[m]] -> (Placed[#, Center] & /@ Flatten[m])];
options = {VertexShapeFunction -> "Square", VertexSize -> {0.1, 0.1}, 
   ImagePadding -> 20, VertexStyle -> Hue[0.125`, 0.7`, 0.9`], 
   ImageSize -> 400, BaseStyle -> Arrowheads[Large]};

g = Graph[el, options, VertexLabels -> vlabels, 
  GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> (Length /@ m)}]
```

[image]

```
Show[g, Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> (gl = DeleteDuplicates /@ Transpose@GraphEmbedding[g]), 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Transpose[{gl[[1]], Range[0, 3]}], None}}]
```

[image]