# Alignment of `TreePlot`

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I want to construct a binomial tree using `TreePlot` but have troubles with the alignment. The code `TreePlot[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 6}, Left, 1, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabeling -> True]` produces the following image:[image: treeplot]

How can I make something like this?:

[image: desiredoutput]

EDIT: The image MMA produces: https://i.stack.imgur.com/txqdi.jpg. The image I would like to have: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ocuw4.jpg.

Comment: @belisariushassettled, I added links to the images.

Comment: There is `NestedSymmetricSubdivision` function in `ref / Traingle` just before `Properties & Relations` section. One could use it for `VertexCoordinates`.

Comment: related q/a: [Drawing the schematic diagram of algorithm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63471/125)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The idea is simple: we take the graph made by `TreePlot` and we change (the coordinates of) the points for the graph nodes into more regularly spaced points.

The solution below attempts to be somewhat robust.

1. The arguments and options taken by `TreePlot` can be used.
2. There is a check for is it possible the symmetric layout of the binary tree be done in such a way that the symmetricity is preserved for the tree sub-branches. See the last plot for which this is not the case.

I hope the code below is easy enough to follow.

```
Clear[MakeSymmetricTreePlot]
MakeSymmetricTreePlot[graphRules_, additionalArgs___, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Block[{pos, gr, points, brect, pointGroups, newxs, newys, newPoints, 
         prules, xi = 1, yi = 2},
   If[Length[{additionalArgs}] == 0, pos = Top, pos = First@{additionalArgs}];
   gr = TreePlot[graphRules, additionalArgs, opts];
   points = Cases[gr, GraphicsComplex[p_, ___] :> p, Infinity][[1]];
   (*Making the new points.*)
   If[pos === Top || pos === Bottom, {xi, yi} = {yi, xi}];
   brect = RegionBounds[Point[points]];
   pointGroups = SortBy[GroupBy[points, Round[#[[xi]], 10^-8] &],Length];
   newxs = Keys[pointGroups];
   If[And @@ 
     Map[#[[1]] + 1 == #[[2]] &, 
      Partition[Length /@ Values[pointGroups], 2, 1]],
    (*We can do a locally symmetric layout.*)
    newys = Reverse@
      NestList[
       If[Length[#] == 2, {Mean[#]}, Mean /@ Partition[#, 2, 1]] &, 
       Values[pointGroups][[-1]][[All, yi]], 
       Length[pointGroups] - 1],
    (*ELSE*)
    newys = Map[
       Apply[Range, 
          Append[brect[[yi]], 
           Abs[Subtract @@ brect[[yi]]]/(# + 1)]][[2 ;; -2]] &, 
       Length /@ Values[pointGroups]];
   ];
   If[pos === Top || pos === Bottom,
    newPoints = 
     MapThread[Outer[List, #2, {#1}][[All, 1]] &, {newxs, newys}],
    newPoints = MapThread[Outer[List, {#1}, #2][[1]] &, {newxs, newys}]
   ];
   (*Make rules from old to new points and replace them in the graph graphics.*)
   prules = 
    Flatten@MapThread[
      Thread[#1 -> #2] &, {Values[pointGroups], newPoints}];
   gr /. prules
 ];
```

Some examples follow.

```
graphRules = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 6};
MakeSymmetricTreePlot[graphRules, Left, 1, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image]

```
graphRules = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 7, 
   4 -> 8, 5 -> 8, 5 -> 9, 6 -> 9, 6 -> 10};
MakeSymmetricTreePlot[graphRules, Right, DirectedEdges -> True, 
 VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image]

```
graphRules = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 7, 
   4 -> 8, 5 -> 9, 5 -> 10, 6 -> 11, 6 -> 12};
MakeSymmetricTreePlot[graphRules, DirectedEdges -> True, 
 VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: The code indeed is easy to follow, thank you!

Comment: @Skumin Great then, I am glad it is working out.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in graph layout `"MultipartiteEmbedding"` as

```
GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> Range[n]}
```

where `n` is the number of layers in the tree.

```
edges1 = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 6};
Graph[Sort @ VertexList[edges1], edges1, GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram", 
 GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> Range[3]}]
```

[image]

```
edges2 = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 7, 
  4 -> 8, 5 -> 8, 5 -> 9, 6 -> 9, 6 -> 10, 7 -> 11, 7 -> 12, 8 -> 12, 
  8 -> 13, 9 -> 13, 9 -> 14, 10 -> 14, 10 -> 15, 11 -> 16, 11 -> 17, 
  12 -> 17, 12 -> 18, 13 -> 18, 13 -> 19, 14 -> 19, 14 -> 20, 
  15 -> 20, 15 -> 21}; 

g = Graph[Sort @ VertexList[edges2], edges2, GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram", 
 GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> Range[6]}]
```

[image]

To change the orientation, you can transform the vertex coordinates:

```
embedding = GraphEmbedding[g];
Row[SetProperty[g, {AspectRation -> 1,
 VertexCoordinates -> (# /@ embedding)] & /@ 
   {ReflectionTransform[{Max[embedding[[All, 2]]], 0}], 
    RotationTransform[-Pi/2], 
    RotationTransform[Pi/2]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, simple, and easy-to-read!